# pandas: losing other columns when merging on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Trying to combine:

df1:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Freddy | Smiths | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Jacoby | Munson | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

df2:

| Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Freddy | Smiths | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Jacoby | Munson | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

to get dfresult:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Freddy | Smiths | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Freddy | Smiths | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Jacoby | Munson | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Jacoby | Munson | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

I tried:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on=['Column A','Column B'], right_on=['Column E','Column F'])
```

and it's giving me:

| Column A | Column B | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Freddy | Smiths | Freddy | Smiths | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Jacoby | Munson | Jacoby | Munson | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

Everything I've read in the documentation indicates columns from both sources should be added.
I noticed the problem when I tried to use Column C and it couldn't find it. So I printed it out with this:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
print(DF.head())
```

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong or a better way to do this?

EDIT: I found the problem. Pandas adds an index to each dataframe when I brought them in from excel. For some reason, the index to df1 was deleted. Adding it back with df1.reset_index() solved the issue.

Comment: With the data provided, I simply end up with your desired `dfresult`, as one would expect. Maybe double check your variables, do `df1` and `df2` really look like they do here, when you apply `df1.merge(...)`?

Comment: I agree with @ouroboros1, getting the same correct results.

Comment: this looks like a `join`

Comment: Yeah, I printed out df1 and df2. They look like they should. The actual dataframes are ~5 columns, 100,000 rows, but apart from that, I can't find any meaningful difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `join` to achieve this.

Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

# the data
d1 = {
    'Column A':['Freddy', 'Jacoby'],
    'Column B':['Smiths', 'Munson'],
    'Column C':['Cell 1', 'Cell 1'],
    'Column D':['Cell 2', 'Cell 2'],
}

d2 = {
    'Column E':['Freddy', 'Jacoby'],
    'Column F':['Smiths', 'Munson'],
    'Column G':['Cell 1', 'Cell 1'],
    'Column H':['Cell 2', 'Cell 2'],
}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2) 

df3 = df1.join(df2)

print(df3)
```

with an output like this:

```
  Column A Column B Column C Column D Column E Column F Column G Column H
0   Freddy   Smiths   Cell 1   Cell 2   Freddy   Smiths   Cell 1   Cell 2
1   Jacoby   Munson   Cell 1   Cell 2   Jacoby   Munson   Cell 1   Cell 2
```